# Modelo de User Django extendido no guarda completa la imformación

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Estoy trabajando con Django 1.10 y necesite extender el modelo `User` de Django para agregar dos campos que necesito, el problema esta en que al momento de grabar me genera error.

Este es mi archivo `models.py`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/photos/')
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

Archivo `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
def usuario_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usuario = User()
        usuario.first_name = request.POST['nombres']
        usuario.last_name = request.POST['apellidos']
        usuario.username = request.POST['cedula']
        usuario.is_superuser = request.POST['perfil']
        usuario.password = make_password(request.POST['psw'])
        usuario.foto = 'static/photos/default.png'
        usuario.empresa = Empresa.objects.get(pk = 1)
        usuario.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/usuario_create')
    else:          
        return render(request,'usuario_create.html')
```

Este es el error que me genera:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1364, "Field 'foto' doesn't have a default value")
```

Agradezco su colaboración.

Answer (score 0):

Imagefield requiere un valor por defecto, como no se lo estas asignando arroja dicho error. Tienes 2 opciones:

Darle valor por defecto:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/photos/', default='static/photos/default.png')
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

Definirle que permita el campo vacio:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/photos/', blank=True, null=True)
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```